# how to not stop the autocomplete if a space is inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Since the max length for user name can be 18  I dont make an ajax call `term.length>2 && term.length < 18`,so far so good but when I type something like this it continues to make the ajax call

```
ex : testing for mentions : @name and now spaces!!!       ;
```

This is the js code i'm using.

```
$("#input").load().bind("blur keydown keypress keyup",function(){

var t = $("#input").val();

suggest(t);

function split(val){
return val.split(/@\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term){
return split(term).pop();
}

function suggest(inputString){
 if(inputString.indexOf("@")>=0){
        term=extractLast(inputString);

    if(term.length>2 && term.length < 18){
        $('#postInput').addClass('load');
        var data = 'name=' + term;
       $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url:"http://site.com/ajax/mentions",
               data:""+term+"",
               dataType:"html",
               success:function(data){
                                      if(data.length>0){$('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                                      $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                                      $('#input').removeClass('load');}
                                    }
        });     
    }
    else {
$('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    }
 }
}
});
```

Comment: Could you please put "console.log(term + "has a length :" + term.length); above $ajax call inorder to see param that it tries to send to the url?

Comment: What happens if you remove `keydown` and `keypress` from the events you're binding to the input?

Comment: Since after **@** there is name = 4

Comment: @Chopin well it does the same thing :) And if i press the space bar it make a ajax call every thme

Comment: Be aware, if you do that way, you will be firing the ajax call multiple times, one for every event.

Comment: yeah that will be bad .. thats why i looking for way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/64ag5/

I've re-formated your code. Basically, you have declared the functions `split`, `extractLast` and `suggest` inside the anonymous function declared on `bind("blur keydown keypress keyup")`.

Also note, `keypresss` and `keydown` fires when the user inputs the 18th character, but before the character is available in the `value` property of the input. So at that instant, the text length will still be 17.

My recommendation is to only handle the `keyup` event. Doing so, ensures the max length validation.

Comment: okey I will change it :) thanks @Chopin but still if the space bar is clicked it makes the ajax call

Comment: @EvenJohnson What is exactly your input?

Comment: Trailing spaces are still considered in the string after `split`. You can `trim()` if that is what you want.

Comment: Ok, I get it. You can check the keycode, to detect whether is a space or not. But you have to distinguish if it was added at the end or in the middle of the name, if you care.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery autocomplete plugin [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

It is easy to use

Comment: I dont want to use plugins :(